# how to globally unalias rm cp mv in RHEL 7

Tags: rhel, alias, rm, cp, mv

from a clean instal of RHEL 7.9 x86_64, all users (including root) have a `bash` shell.

And the commands `mv` and `cp` and `rm` are aliased to have the `i` option to them.

Which I do not like; how does one *properly* unalias these 3 items globally so when anyone uses them they are not always prompted with the *are you sure*?

I can't find what file under `/etc` has `alias rm='rm -i'`  {and for cp and for mv}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe all users have these aliases. For the `root` user, the aliases are set in `/root/.bashrc`. New users don't have these aliases. For example, on a RHEL 7 system:

```
[root@example /]# useradd testuser
[root@example /]# su - testuser
[testuser@example ~]$ alias
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias l.='ls -d .* --color=auto'
alias ll='ls -l --color=auto'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
[testuser@example ~]$
```

Comment: yes I think you are correct; I noticed this shortly after asking.  In `/root/.bashrc` it has the 3 aliases for `rm, cp, mv`  that I need to simply comment out as the fix {which is only present for the root account}.  Thanks.